# get popup calender in c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, forms, calendar

how can i show a **popup** calender in a form,when anyone trying to input date.

**Code**

```
<form class="form" novalidate name="f1" ng-submit="CustomerReg()">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label> Date</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  autocomplete="off" placeholder=" Date"
         name="Date" ng-model="CustomerData.Date" 
         ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required>
  <span class="error" ng-show="(f1.Date.$dirty || Submitted) && f1.Date.$error.required">Date Required</span>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS supports HTML5 `<input type="date">`:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder=" Date"
       name="Date" ng-model="CustomerData.Date" required>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `<input type="date">` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateTimePicker">
```

have you tried to set type from text to date?